# Repeater itemdatabound event value type and reference type

Tags: asp.net, events, repeater, itemdatabound

Im trying to bind a list with datetime objects to my repeater.

if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                DateTime actualDate = e.Item.DataItem as DateTime; 
            }

When I want access the itemdatabound event on the repeater 
Then I get an errormessage which says that DateTime is a valuetype and not a reference type.
My solution is that a wrap the datetime in a custom object (reference type) and pass that to the repeater datasource instead of the datetime. But Im wondering if there are other solutions where the repeater takes valuetypes (DateTime objects)........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not correctly typing the DataItem

```
if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || 
      e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) 
{ DateTime actualDate = (DateTime)e.Item.DataItem; }
```